# Split vector randomly into two sets

Tags: r, sample, random

I have a vector t with length 100 and want to divide it into 30 and 70 values but the values should be chosen randomly and without replacement. So none of the 30 values are allowed to be in the sub vector of the 70 values and vice versa.

I know the R function `sample` which I can use to randomly chose values from a vector with and without replacement. However, even when I use replace = FALSE I have to run the `sample` function twice once with 30 and once with 70 values to chose. That means that some of the 30 values might be in the 70 values and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Comment: Am confused. Why can't you select 30 at random using `sample()` then select everything *other* than 30 random sample as the other set. By definition this two sets will be unique.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, that's pretty much what I did in my answer, just adding a grouping variable to split by; but, I'm still not sure what they're actually looking for.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I tried different solutions and they all seem to work. I just came across a different R package: ftp://ftp.ee.freebsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/math/R-e1071/README.html which does actually what I want. However, I do not get it installed at all. I downloaded the .tgz file and tried to install it but it failed...

Comment: Are you running FreeBSD? If not why are you trying to to install one of its tarballs? Use whatever facilities your flavour of R provides to install the package, but if you have internet, start R and do `install.packages("e1071"), depend = TRUE)` to install the package and then `library("e1071")` to load it ready for use in the current session.

Comment: Could you also reply to the comments asking for clarification as to what you wanted to achieve? There is some confusion and most of the answers will fail if `t` has non-unique values.

Comment: All of the answers here are quite straightforward: I'm not sure why you would want to use a package to solve the problem anyway, unless it has other complications you have not mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
t <- 1:100 # or whatever your original set is
a <- sample(t, 70)
b <- setdiff(t, a)
```

Comment: Same comment as for some other entries; the `setdiff()` approach only works if `isTRUE(all(!duplicated(t)))`. It "fails" if there are repeated values.

Comment: Agreed, but I suspect that the OP has a vector with unique values (otherwise, it would seem less important to avoid sampling with replacement).

Comment: In that case, once you have the first sample (of say 30) you can take the others by negative indexing, you don't need `setdiff()`. It is a bit of over kill for this job is it not?

Comment: It is when `t` is `1:100` but the above approach would work for any vector `t` of unique entries. Of course the alternative would be to stick to sampling `1:100` and use negative indexing, but have the sample represent the index not the sample, as you did.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding my comment, what is wrong with:

```
vec <- 1:100
set.seed(2)
samp <- sample(length(vec), 30)

a <- vec[samp]
b <- vec[-samp]
```

?

To show these are separate sets with no duplicates:

```
R> intersect(a, b)
integer(0)
```

If you have duplicate values in your vector that is a different matter, but your question is unclear.

With duplicates in `vec` things are a bit more complicated and it depends what result you wanted to achieve.

```
R> set.seed(4)
R> vec <- sample(100, 100, replace = TRUE)
R> set.seed(6)
R> samp <- sample(100, 30)
R> a <- vec[samp]
R> b <- vec[-samp]
R> length(a)
[1] 30
R> length(b)
[1] 70
R> length(setdiff(vec, a))
[1] 41
```

So the `setdiff()` "fails" here as it doesn't get the length right, but then `a` and `b` contain duplicate values (but not observations! from the sample):

```
R> intersect(a, b)
 [1] 57 35 91 27 71 63  8 92 49 77
```

The duplicates (intersection) arises because the values above occurred twice in the original sample `vec`

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this?

```
x <- 1:100
s70 <- sample(x, 70, replace=FALSE)
s30 <-sample(setdiff(x, s70), 30, replace=FALSE)
```

`s30` will have the same numbers as `setdiff(x, s70)`, the difference between them is:
`s30` an unordered vector of length 30 and `setdiff(x, s70)` will give you an (ascending) ordered vector of length 30. You said you want random subsamples of length 70 and 30 so `s30` is better than just `setdiff(x, s70)`. If order does not really matter, so the better alternative will be using `setdiff` without `sample` as in @seancarmody's answer.

Comment: Snap! Although you don't really need the sample in the second example, unless you want to shuffle the order, which is not really clear in the OP ("divide into 30 and 70 values...")

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned "split", you can also try something like this:

```
set.seed(1)
t <- sample(20:40, 100, replace=TRUE)
groups <- rep("A", 100)
groups[sample(100, 30)] <- "B"
table(groups)
# groups
#  A  B 
# 70 30
split(t, groups)
# $A
#  [1] 25 32 39 24 38 39 33 21 24 23 36 40 27 36 24 33 22 25 28 28 38 27 30 30 23
# [26] 34 35 37 33 31 36 20 30 35 34 30 29 25 22 26 33 28 26 29 26 33 30 36 21 38
# [51] 27 37 27 27 30 38 38 36 29 34 28 26 35 25 23 25 21 33 36 28
# 
# $B
#  [1] 27 33 34 28 30 35 39 20 32 37 36 22 28 36 31 38 21 30 39 25 28 40 24 34 22
# [26] 38 36 29 37 32
```

Comment: I think the OP wants samples without replacement and those values in the first vector must not be contained in the second vector. Doesn't he?

Comment: @Jilber, I don't think the question is totally clear. If I use my "t" and your answer or Sean's, the first step is fine, but the second step doesn't work. Have you tried your answer with less tidy data than 1:100? My *assumption* was that they were concerned about selecting a number based on its index or position, and not the value.

Comment: Based on your assumption you are right. And yes, the question is not clear enough.